# Is it possible to have a ready initiated colorbox/lightbox/thickbox etc on the show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox, colorbox, thickbox

I have added colorbox to my app to display photos added via paperclip to my venue records.

**venue show.html.erb**

```
<div class="venue_photos_container">
  <% for venuephoto in @venue.venuephotos %>
    <div class="venue_photo_thumb_container"><%= link_to image_tag(venuephoto.venuephoto.url(:thumb), :class => "venue_photo"), venuephoto.venuephoto.url(:original), :rel => "venue_photo_colorbox" %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This shows all the uploaded photos for that venue as 100x100 thumbnails in the venue_photos_container div and when one is clicked it loads up the colorbox viewer window and lets the user flick left and right between the thumbnailed pics.

Is there a way to not display thumbnails of the uploaded pics and instead have a ready initiated colorbox window which only fills the venue_photos_container div so the rest of the page can still be used as normal?

So the venue_photos_container div is filled with the first image uploaded and has the prev and next buttons on either side of it to let the user flick between the photos.

I hope this makes sense,

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/colorbox.htm has done the trick!